# User picking image and hover state image for menu, ends up flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

in a project we are working on we let the user choose the pictures for his menu as well as the hover state picture for each menu. Right now the menu consists from x amount of `div` tags, based on the user selection we set the style of the div in order to apply the image as background and on `mouseover` and `onmouseout` we change the style attribute.

However this results in image flickering which is not ideal. What I would like is a result like a sprite hover with css, but in this case I don't know how to achieve or approach something like this. If I'm not mistaken the image is being requested again and again hence the flickering ?

current source code:

```
<div class="help-context-box" style="background-image: url(http://domain.com/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=db77cbf4-6ae8-42ec-bb07-36cbde8ab82a&amp;groupId=10180); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"
onmouseover="this.style.background='#fff url(/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=bd77adc5-54c7-42c8-b39d-f07f1d611ac0&amp;groupId=10180) no-repeat left top'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#fff url(/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=db77cbf4-6ae8-42ec-bb07-36cbde8ab82a&amp;groupId=10180) no-repeat left top'"></div>
```

Comment: There are three images right now. Are ok with a solution having them all in one image (sprite) provided by you? Another question: can you use CSS3 multiple backgrounds?

Comment: no sprites can not be used because the user uploads images of their choice as separate files. I would avoid css3 to be honest, because they want backwards compatibility

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, I think you must use GD from php or other graphic libraries in order to append both images in a sprite then use

```
<div class="help-context-box" 
style="background-image: url(...); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='50% 0'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='50% 0'"></div>
```

Or without using inline nor javascript:

**HTML**

```
<div class="help-context-box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.help-context-box{
  background:url(path/to/usersprit.png) no-repeat;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-position:0% 0%;
}

.help-context-box:hover{
  background-position:-100% 0%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NKCq/)